# How do I scrape data from a public SharePoint URL using Python?

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, sharepoint

I am trying to scrape data from a Sharepoint URL and save that data to a local excel file.
The file saves but it doesnt have the data from the online excel spreadsheet.

```
import requests

url = 'https://crokepark-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/personal/ruairi_harvey_gaa_ie/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?guestaccesstoken=Gc2myfwceMcTJO0Sm78dGMt4Up6MH9VlzlUxxsMV%2Fgk%3D&docid=04bc452cba06b4bfea0d1ed80a2b5fac6&action=default&cid=f2e59e9a-71fd-4fd4-aaa6-8e3a4e88fe40'
response = requests.get(url)

with open('file.HTML', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Open the HTML file
with open("file.html", "r") as file:
    html_content = file.read()

# Use BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

# Find the table in the HTML using its attributes (e.g. class, id)
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'table-class-name'})
soup 

# Extract the table headers
headers = [header.text for header in table.find_all('Aimn')]

# Extract the table data rows
rows = []
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    rows.append([cell.text for cell in row.find_all('td')])

# Print the table headers and data
print(headers)
print(rows)
```

The error says it can't find the header in the table.
After inspecting the Soup data I don't see any of the data on the excel file.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_4532/3438091026.py in <module>
      1 # Extract the table headers
----> 2 headers = [header.text for header in table.find_all('Aimn')]
      3 
      4 # Extract the table data rows
      5 rows = []

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, the response might be empty. Have you tried to print the values you get to debug your code? Oh, and you are trying to write a CSV as bytes. Are you sure you want to use `"wb"` instead of `"w"` when opening the file?

Comment: code updated. I had to use "wb" as "w" won't work

Comment: You won't find the table data in the HTML because the data is loaded dynamically. If you check the Network tab in your browser inspector, you will see a request that starts with `https://euc-excel.officeapps.live.com/x/_layouts/xlviewerinternal.aspx`. This request contains the data shown in the table, which is formatted with a script in the front end. You can try extracting the data from that endpoint and parsing the HTML.